# "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program" when scraping website

Tags: powershell, memory, windows-10

I am trying to scrape a website with PowerShell on Windows 10.

I can get a full list of attributes on the site by calling `$ie.document`, but when I try to call `$ie.document.getElementById("a-button")` I get the following message:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

I haven't had any luck finding a solution for this.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you give the Web site you are trying to scrape ?

Comment: Do you _have_ sufficient memory to continue the operation? What does Task Manager report when you run this?

Comment: This is the person that asked the question. I am scraping a page on Amazon to buy something automatically. At work on a laptop with lower stats than my workstation at home it seems to be just fine. My Workstation at home has 24GB ram and it usually sits at about 11-15%. My Laptop has similar stats as my work computer where it works.